# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ChildrenProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-context

I'm currently working on a React project with Typescript, and to be honest, I'm having a lot of trouble with this. I'm trying to create a context to share a useState, but I'm getting the following error on `value={{ isOpen, setIsOpen }}`:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; value: { isOpen: boolean; setIsOpen: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ChildrenProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ChildrenProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

I searched for solutions on Stackoverflow, but no answer helped me. Here is my code:

```
import { PropsWithChildren, createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const MenuContext = createContext<MenuContextType>({
  isOpen: false,
  setIsOpen: () => {},
});

interface MenuContextType {
  isOpen: boolean;
  setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

interface ChildrenProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export function MenuContextProvider({
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<ChildrenProps>) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MenuContextProvider value={{ isOpen, setIsOpen }}>
      {children}
    </MenuContextProvider>
  );
}

export const useMenuContext = () => {
  useContext(MenuContext);
};
```

I've tried passing 'MenuContext' as the value or even just 'isOpen'. I've also tried passing { isOpen: isOpen, setIsOpen: setIsOpen } as the value, but this doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in the code. The problem is that the return statement is using `MenuContextProvider` instead of `MenuContext.Provider`. This will cause an error and prevent the context value from being passed to the `children` components.

To fix this, you need to change `MenuContextProvider` to `MenuContext.Provider`, which is the correct way to use the context provider component.

For example:

```
return (
  <MenuContext.Provider value={{ isOpen, setIsOpen }}>
    {children}
  </MenuContext.Provider>
);
```

---

### Updated Answer

You need to return the value of `useContext(MenuContext)` so that you can access the `isOpen` and `setIsOpen` properties in your child component.

For example:

```
export const useMenuContext = () => {
  return useContext(MenuContext);
};
```

Comment: Thanks man, I feel so dumb sorry... Now I have an other error but I should be able to solve it.

Comment: Don't worry. If you have a question, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Now, when I try to use isOpen, setIsOpen (or isOpenValue, setIsOpenValue) in a child component, I got this error:
Property 'setIsOpen' does not exist on type 'void'.

I think it's because of an error in my context file because my inspector says: 
Cannot destructure property 'isOpen' of 'useMenuContext(...)' as it is undefined.

Comment: The problem is that you are not returning anything from your useMenuContext hook. I updated my answer. please check it - @ImEmo

Comment: Yes, I did that but it didn't work because of an error in my other file. Thanks, you helped me a lot